# Alignment of Margin caption with floatrow and caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, floatrow

I want my captions in marginpar to be left aligned. I am using `raggedright` option in `caption` package along with `floatrow` package. The captions are left aligned only for long captions.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{geometry,caption,floatrow}

\geometry{showframe=true, includemp,marginparwidth=5cm, marginparsep=1em}
%
\newlength{\figWidthForMarginCap}%
\setlength{\figWidthForMarginCap}{\textwidth}%
\addtolength{\figWidthForMarginCap}{-1em}%
\addtolength{\figWidthForMarginCap}{\marginparsep}%
%
\captionsetup{
  format=plain,
  margin=0em,
  labelsep=newline,
  justification=raggedright
}
%
\begin{document}
  \thisfloatsetup{%
    capposition=beside,
    capbesidewidth=\marginparwidth,
    capbesideposition={bottom,right},
    floatwidth=\figWidthForMarginCap
  }
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{2cm}
    \caption{Small Caption}
    %\caption{This is a needlessly long caption to which runs at least two lines.}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use option `singlelinecheck=false`.

```
\captionsetup{
  format=plain,
  margin=0em,
  labelsep=newline,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false
}
```

I quote from the `caption` manual:

> The standard LATEX document classes (article, report, and book) automatically center a
>   caption if it fits in one single line...
>
> The [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package adapts this behavior and therefore usually ignores the justification
>   & indention you have set with justification= & indention= in such case. But
>   you can switch this special treatment of such short captions off with the option
>
> `singlelinecheck=<bool>`
>
> Using `false`, `no`, `off` or `0` for `bool` switches the extra centering off